# Create a CSV file in python

Tags: python, file, csv

I would like to copy a specific structure of a CSV file and add my own information to it. The file I would like to copy looks like:

```
ID      file_name coordinates_X coordinates_Y height width
034033  img/1.jpg 0             0             512    512
021364  img/2.jpg 0             0             512    512  
...     ...       ...           ...           ...    ...
```

I would like to create a similar file. The code I have so far:

```
dir_ = ... # my path
list_items =  #my list
with open('new.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
lines = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
for file in list_items:
    lines.writerow(file+','+ dir_+ file +','+ str(0)+','+ str(0)+','+ str(256)+','+ str(256))
    print (dir_ + file)
```

That approach seems that writes every single character in a different cell. I would like to write in each cell one string instead. How can I do so?

Comment: The *whole point* of using the `csv` module is that you don't have to add your own commas in. Give it the *items*, let it add the separators (and quotes, and whatever else).

Comment: If you have possibility of usage of external modules you might consider using pandas https://pypi.org/project/pandas/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a `list` to `writerow`

**Ex:**

```
dir_ = ... # my path
list_items =  #my list
with open('new.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    lines = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for file in list_items:
        lines.writerow([file, dir_+ file, str(0), str(0), str(256),str(256)])
        print (dir_ + file)
```